# Is there any way to override methods in NetBeans automatically?

Tags: java, netbeans, superclass, overriding

I have to do some overriding on several Java classes from one super class. I used suggestions and shortcuts to do so. NetBeans do automatically override the methods.

But when I need to change a method in the super class, I have to do it one by one. Is there any method to override them automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to NetBeans, it can be done easily.

Imagine this is your project structure:

```
refactordemo
|-- Parent.java
|-- Child.java
```

and this is the Sample code:

**Parent.java**

```
package refactordemo;
public class Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public String method1() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
package refactordemo;
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    @Override
    public String method1() {
        return super.method1();
    }
}
```

Notice that the `method1()` of `class Child` overrides `method1()` of `class Parent`.

Now, if you want to change the signature (return type, method name, parameters) of `method1()` in `class Parent` and want those changes in all the child classes, then NetBeans is just what you need.

1. **Go to Parent.java (parent class)**
2. **Find the method whose signature you want to change (`method1()` in this case)**
3. **Right click on the method name**
4. **Go to Refactor > Change Method Parameters...**
   [image]

There... you have it all.

**What stuff can you do here:**

[image]

1. **Add / Remove parameters.**
2. **Change data type of existing parameters.**
3. **Change access modifier of the method.**
4. **Change return type of the method.**
5. **Change the name of the method.**

[image: The changes I did]

After making the required changes, click 'Refactor' at the bottom of the window.

Anytime better than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>

Please note that I am using **NetBeans 8.0.1** but as per my knowledge this feature is present since **NetBeans 7.3**

Comment: Woow thanks bro :D that the exact thing i wanted. U saved me and my time.

Comment: Again Thanks for your helpfulness and explaining effort mate :) Cheers :)

Comment: @Thanuj That's what StackOverflow is for. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Refactor menu -> Change method signature. It will take care of all overrides for you.